# How do you compute a total differential when two ore more variables are changing simultaneously, and their partial derivative depend on each other.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do you compute a total differential when two ore more variables are changing simultaneously, and their partial derivative depend on each other.

Say I have $y = f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$
and 
$dy/dx_1$ depends on $x_2$,
$dy/dx_2$ depends on $x_1$,

and both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are changing at the same time.

In particular I want to distill the part of the change on y that is explained by the change in $x_1$, and the part that is explained by $x_2$.

I computed the total differential as it's done in any calculus textbook:
$$dy = f'_{x_1}dx_1 + f'_{x_2}dx_2 + f'_{x_3}dx_3 + f'_{x_4}dx_4$$
But what I get doesn't add up to the change I see in $y$.

I figured it's because, as I said, the partial derivatives of $x_1$ and $x_2$ depend on the other variable, but I don't really know how to deal with this... Maybe it's really simple, but I've been thinking it out for a couple of hours and I can't come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest example of the phenomenon you describe is to take
$$f(x,y) = xy,$$
so $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x$. Suppose you start at $(x,y)=(a,b)$ and make small changes $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ to $x$ and $y$ respectively. If you fix $y=b$ and vary $x$, then the area of the rectangle changes precisely by the amount $b\Delta x$ (which is $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)\Delta x$. If you fix $x=a$ and vary $y$, the area changes, analogously, by $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)\Delta y$. [In terms of the total change, if you draw the picture, you see that you *do* get the net change in $f(x,y)$ "to first order": You're missing only the tiny rectangle with area $\Delta x\Delta y$.]

What seems to be confusing you is that the rate of change of $f$ with respect to $x$ may, in fact, be $y$. Indeed, only rarely does $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ depend only on $x$. You're misinterpreting what the partial derivative means if you expect that to be the case.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I think I see the conceptual confusion I had. Do you have any input into how one would go about determining the share each variable x1, x2, x3 and x4 had into the change of y?

Comment: What you're thinking isn't going to be linear approximation. It amounts to looking at the function in its entirety, and I'm not sure what you want other than the formula you started with.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure either. I'll think harder and try to put my ideas in order. Thank you anyway, making me see the confusion was a big step!